# How can I hide my Google Maps API key in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in javascript. I made a sample website where it runs Google Maps and I have my API Key. How can I hide the API Key so that others won't steal it?

```
<script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[THE_KEY_HERE]&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

I was thinking if I can make a variable for the key and store it in another js but I don't know how can I insert in the `src`.

Comment: You can not hide anything that is loaded to client's browser. You can have a look at [this official page](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)

Answer (score 4):

> I was thinking if I can make a variable for the key and store it in another js but I don't know how can I insert in the src.

That's pointless. You'd still have to give it to the browser.

See [API Key Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices):

> To set an application restriction for an API key
>
> 1. Visit the credentials panel.
> 2. Select the API key that you want to set a restriction on. The API key property page appears.
> 3. Under Key restrictions, select Application restrictions.
>      Select one of the restriction types and supply the requested information following the restriction list.
>
> HTTP referrers
>
> Accept requests from the list of websites that you supply.
>
> Below the types, specify one or more referrer web sites. Wildcard characters are acceptable for naming similar web sites. For example, *.google.com accepts all sites ending in google.com, such as https://developers.google.com.